# Changing a property of all objects in an array in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an array that stores objects of two types. These two types are `OwnMessageCard` and `ReplyCard`. I use Socket.IO in my project.

```
late IO.Socket _socket;
var myMessagesList = < Widget > [];
_connectSocket() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myUsername = prefs.getString('myUsername') !;

    _socket.onConnect((data) => print('Connection established'));
    _socket.onConnectError((data) => print('Connection error: $data'));
    _socket.onDisconnect((data) => print('Socket disconnected.'));
    _socket.on(myUsername, (data) {
        setState(() {
            myMessagesList.add(ReplyCard(
                senderMessage: data['message'].toString(),
                sentAt: data['sentAt'].toString(),
            ));
        });
        _socket.emit('seen', {
            'sender': myUsername,
            'target': targetUsername
        });
    });
    _socket.on("$myUsername/seen", (data) {
        setState(() {
            myMessagesList.forEach((element) {
                if (element == OwnMessageCard) {
                    //Some codes here to change 'isSeen' property to 'true'

                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I want to set `isSeen` property of all `OwnMessageCard` object to `true` when a message comes from `_socket.on("$myUsername/seen", (data){}`.
`OwnMessageCard` has two properties of `myMessage` and `isSeen`.
How can I do that?

**Update**: `OwnMessageCard` class:

```
class OwnMessageCard extends StatelessWidget {
  OwnMessageCard({super.key, required this.myMessage, required this.isSeen});
  final String myMessage;
  bool isSeen;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentTime = DateTime.now();
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 45, minWidth: 180),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 1,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
          color: ownMessageBackColor,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 5),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 25, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 25),
                child: Text(
                  myMessage,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'FMitra'),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 4,
                right: 10,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.done_all,
                      size: 20,
                      color: isSeen ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "${currentTime.hour}:${currentTime.minute} | ${currentTime.year}-${currentTime.month}-${currentTime.day}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `element.isSeen = true` ???

Comment: @AnteBule I tested it. There is an error in `isSeen` and says: `The setter 'isSeen' isn't defined for the type 'Widget'.`

Comment: Try `element is OwnMessageCard` instead of `element == OwnMessageCard`

Comment: @AnteBule It's saying `'isSeen' can't be used as a setter because it's final.`

Comment: Remove `final` on `isSeen` property in your `OwnMessageCard` class

Comment: can you include OwnMessageCard class model? @AlexWright

Comment: Thanks. It solved. But `isSeen` does not affect the UI in real-time. It takes effect when I refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can't compare variable with type by `==` , you need to use `is`, second you can change your data like this, I assume this is your class model:

```
class OwnMessageCard {
  final bool isSeen;
  final String message;

  OwnMessageCard({
    required this.isSeen,
    required this.message,
  });
}
```

and you can change your data like this:

```
_socket.on("$myUsername/seen", (data) {
        var newList = myMessagesList.map((e) => e is OwnMessageCard ? OwnMessageCard(isSeen: true,message: e.message ) : e)
            .toList();

        setState(() {
            myMessagesList = newList;
        });
    });
```